Generar instancias de beans CDI con Calificadores
Qué tal chicos, buen día.
Me estoy enfrentando a un reto en java, estoy usando la versión 17 de java con el Framework de Quarkus en su versión 3.7.3, el caso es el siguiente:
Estoy haciendo una implementación para consumir mensajes por JMS (eso ya lo hago sin algún problema), cada vez que creo por ejemplo un listener, le paso a un método el nombre de la configuración (del archivo application.yml) que tiene que leer para de ahí obtener los datos, como el nombre de la cola, el número de sesiones máximas que puede tener el listener entre otros datos, actualmente hago algo así:
package org.acme.jms;

import io.quarkus.runtime.ShutdownEvent;
import io.quarkus.runtime.StartupEvent;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.enterprise.event.Observes;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import org.acme.helpers.ObjectsValues;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@ApplicationScoped
public class ListenerTest {
    private final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
    @Inject
    private JMSConsumer listenerPisa;


    void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent event) {
        startListener();
    }
    void onStop(@Observes ShutdownEvent event) {
        stopListener();
    }

    public void startListener(){
        try {
            listenerPisa.setConfiguration("TEST"); //Aquí ingreso la configuración a leer
            listenerPisa.startListener(this::processMessage);
        }catch (JMSException e){
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "No es posible iniciar el listener principal MQ", e);
        }catch (Exception e){
            stopListener();
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error inesperado al iniciar el listener principal MQ", e);
        }
    }

    public void processMessage(TextMessage textMessage, String textBody, Set<Header> clientHeaders, Set<Header> jsmHeaders) {
        try {
            LOGGER.info("Me llegó el mensaje...");;
            System.out.println("Salgo de todo el proceso...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Ocurrió un error en el proceso principal ", e);
        }
        LOGGER.info("Saliendo del proceso...");
    }

    public void stopListener(){
        if(listenerPisa != null){
            try {
                listenerPisa.stopListener();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error al detener listener principal MQ", e);
            }
        }
    }

}

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero me gustaría hacer algo como he visto en otras implementaciones donde por medio de una anotación calificada pones el nombre, por ejemplo como lo hace Agroal donde se hace algo asi:
    @Inject
    @DataSource("testds")
    private AgroalDataSource testDS;

Entonces mi intención es hacer algo así:
    @Inject
    @JMSProfile("TEST") //Donde desde aquí le pueda pasar el nombre del perfil o la configuración que tendrá que leer
    private JMSConsumer listenerPisa;

Ya intenté crear una anotación así:
package org.acme.jms;;

import jakarta.enterprise.util.AnnotationLiteral;
import jakarta.inject.Qualifier;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface JMSProfile {
    String value() default "";
    public class JMSProfileLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<JMSProfile> implements JMSProfile {

        private String value;

        public JMSProfileLiteral(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String value() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}

Y también un método productor:
package org.acme.jms;;

import com.globalhitss.api.service.jms.JMSConsumer2;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;

@ApplicationScoped
public class JMSProducerCDI {
    @Produces
    public JMSConsumer produceParameter(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        JMSProfile annotation = injectionPoint.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(JMSProfile.class);
        if (annotation != null) {
            JMSConsumer jmsConsumer = new JMSConsumer();
            jmsConsumer.init(annotation.value()); //Aquí se le pasa el valor de la configuración
            return jmsConsumer;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No se puede resolver la inyección de dependencia, ya que es requerida ser " +
                "anotada con @JMSProfile"); // Valor por defecto si no se encuentra la anotación
    }
}

Esta implementación no funciona como debería ya que al ser la anotación calificada no encuentra un método productor que cumpla con dicha calificación.
Pueden ayudarme a saber cómo se pudiera implementar.
PD: cabe mencionar que el nombre de la configuración es dinámica y proporcionada por el usuario, dejo ejemplo de cómo está:
    custom:
      mq:
        consumers:
          listeners:
            TEST:
              queueName: "PSVA"
              filter: "TipoSolicitud='PV'"
              max-sessions: 2
              min-sessions: 1
              initial-sessions: 1
              acquisition-timeout: 10000
              max-lifetime: 90000
              removal-interval: 120000
            TEST2:
              queueName: "PSVA"
              filter: "TipoSolicitud='PV'"
              max-sessions: 2
              min-sessions: 1
              initial-sessions: 1
              acquisition-timeout: 10000
              max-lifetime: 90000
              removal-interval: 120000


Queda al pendiente, saludos.
